# <button> event not being fired on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery .click event is not being fired whilst the keyboard is open...

Though its not a major problem but it frustrates my client that the end user needs to click  button twice for a single event... You have to close the keyboard first to get that the event triggered.

I have also tried the same by changing  tag to  tag - but no luck with that too.

I am using bootstrap framework and the button is placed within a modal dialog.

I've been searching, for a long time on this and din't find any luck. So I would really appreciate your help and support.

**UPDATE**

Here is the contents of the modal:

```
<div class="input-group input-sm">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
<input class="form-control" name = "userid" type="text" id="userid" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
<input class="form-control" name = "password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</div>
<div class = 'row' id = "options">
<input type = "hidden" id = "pkey"/>
<input  type=button id = 'sign-in' class = 'btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-5' style = "height:85px;" value = "Sign In" />
<input type=button id = 'sign-out' class = 'btn btn-danger col-xs-12 col-sm-5 pull-right' style = "height:85px;" value = "Sign Out" />
</div>
```

here is the jQuery:

```
$("#staff").click(function () {
checksession();
//hasstaffaccess();
$("#modal-title").html("Staff Login");
$("#modal-body").load("staff.php", function () {
    openmodal();
    $("#sign-in").click(function () {
        //alert($("#userid").val() + $("#password").val());
        $.get("ajax/verifystaff.php?username=" + $("#userid").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val() + "&inout=in", {
            username: $("#userid").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            inout: "in"
        }, function (data) {
            //invalidlogon          

            for (var key in data) {
                //alert(key);
                if (key == "invalidusername" || key == "invalidpassword" || key == "invalidlogon") {
                    alert("Inavild Username/Password");
                }
                if (key == "error") {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
                if (key == "successful_logon") {
                    if (data.successful_logon != "") {
                        updateinstructions(data.successful_logon);
                        closemodal()
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "json");
    })
    $("#sign-out").click(function () {
        //alert($("#userid").val() + $("#password").val());
        $.get("ajax/verifystaff.php?username=" + $("#userid").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val() + "&inout=out", {
            username: $("#userid").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            inout: "out"
        }, function (data) {
            //invalidlogon          

            for (var key in data) {
                //alert(key);
                if (key == "invalidusername" || key == "invalidpassword" || key == "invalidlogon") {
                    alert("Inavild Username/Password");
                }
                if (key == "error") {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
                if (key == "successful_logon") {
                    if (data.successful_logon != "") {
                        updateinstructions(data.successful_logon);
                        closemodal();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "json");
    })


})
})
```

Sorry my coding may not be the most straight forward..... :S

Comment: Please place your code that you've done to we can help. Usually it is a stupid error that knows how to deliver a headache to evry developer. :)

Comment: Could you please upload <a href="http://www.jsfiddle.net">jsfiddle</a> code? <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind to the `touchstart` event.

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchstart

Comment: Thanks! this seams to solve the problem on a test page will now update website and know for sure :)